# Laravel 5.3 Ajax Login

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to login my users with ajax with a new Laravel 5.3 project.

I've generated the auth routes, which got added to my web.php:

```
Auth::routes();
```

I have a html form with email, and password inputs and the csrf field. Then I also have this javascript file:

```
$("form.login").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({   
        method: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: { 
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
        },
        data: $("form.login").serialize(),
        url: "/login"
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

When I post it however, this shows up in my network tab:
[image: chrome dev tools]

It redirects back to the original page, without returning any data.

Why is it doing this? Does 5.3 not give json responses anymore?

Comment: Uhm.. Try adding a `dd()` on the beginning of the login method and check if you can see that dd on the request. If you can, most likely you have a redirect somewhere on that code which should probably be a `Response`. If you don't, most likely the issue lies on the route's middleware.

Answer (score 5):

### The Complete Solution:

Hi reinierkors,

I also tried to do the same with the 5.3 version, I finally solved it :) and the solution is very clean.

First, I **created a new folder** under **App\Http\Controllers\Api** called **Auth**, I did it just to add new auth controllers for the api so I can rewrite some functions, then I copied the auth controllers (*LoginController*, *ForgotPasswordController*, *RegisterController*) to this new folder.

***In LoginController Class:***
I rewrited the functions that were making the redirects.

> **The first function:** will be automatically called when the
> authentication return success.
>
> **The second function:** will be automatically called when the
> authentication return error.
>
> **The last function:** will be automatically called when the user has been
> locked out after trying 5 login attempts.

```
     /**
     * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request) {
        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        return response()->json(['SUCCESS' => 'AUTHENTICATED'], 200);
    }

    /**
     * Get the failed login response instance.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function sendFailedLoginResponse() {
        return response()->json(['ERROR' => 'AUTH_FAILED'], 401);
    }

    /**
     * Error after determining they are locked out.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function sendLockoutResponse(Request $request) {
        $seconds = $this->limiter()->availableIn(
            $this->throttleKey($request)
        );

        return response()->json(['ERROR' => 'TOO_MANY_ATTEMPTS', 'WAIT' => $seconds], 401);
    }
```

***In RegisterController Class:***
I rewrited the functions that were making the redirects.

> **In the first function:** I modified the validator response to return a more comfortable response (array) to work with.
>
> **The second function:** will be automatically called when the registration return success.

```
    /**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request) {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if($validator->fails())
            return response()->json(['ERROR' => $validator->errors()->getMessages()], 422);

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    /**
     * The user has been registered.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param  mixed $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function registered(Request $request, $user) {
        return response()->json(['SUCCESS' => 'AUTHENTICATED']);
    }
```

***In ForgotPasswordController Class:***
I rewrited the function that was making the redirects.

> I modified the reset link email function so we can get the messages and display as json instead of the redirects.

```
     /**
     * Send a reset link to the given user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->only('email'), [
            'email' => 'required|email',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails())
            return response()->json(['ERROR' => 'VALID_EMAIL_REQUIRED'], 422);

        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );

        if ($response === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT) {
            return response()->json(['SUCCESS' => 'EMAIL_SENT'], 200);
        }

        // If an error was returned by the password broker, we will get this message
        // translated so we can notify a user of the problem. We'll redirect back
        // to where the users came from so they can attempt this process again.
        return response()->json(['ERROR' => 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND'], 401);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> For explanation about my mistake (the kind of same as op), see the [edit history of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39739269/2).

### How I solved it

with a little bit of help from [@iSensical](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6643401/isensical)

Inside the `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` there is a `unauthenticated` function which, by default, knows if the request expects a `json` answer with the `expectsJson()` function.

The problem didn't came from Laravel by itself. It was, surprisingly, the human factor. I wrote a bad piece of code.

My ajax request did not used an intuitive header for Laravel.

I had this:

```
$http({
    url     : '{{ route('angular.auth.login.post') }}',
    method  : 'POST',
    data    : $.param($scope.user)+'&x-csrf-token='+CSRF_TOKEN,
    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
})
[...]
```

We might have used a bad `Content-Type`. 
The correct one was `application/json` like this:

```
headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
```

Comment: Assuming config/auth.php is set with default values for auth i.e. web. Verify what you have in Http/Middleware/authenticate.php within handle() function. It should have 

            if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
                return redirect()->guest('login');
        }

if there is code with $request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson() there it should not redirect to 301.

Comment: I don't have that file `Http/Middleware/authenticate.php` but, thanks to you @iSensical, you're right. There is a function which handle this.
In `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` for the version 5.3 there is a `unauthenticated` function which, by default, check if the request expects a Json answer.
I'm going to edit my post to explain how it work for me and where my mistake was.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot. I still can't seem to get it to work, I think they removed the json response altogether in 5.3. Even when adding something like `dataType: "json",` to the ajax request, it will still redirect.