# Laravel 5.3 AJAX login doesn't redirect

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have similar issue like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675978/laravel-5-3-ajax-login).

I'm trying to make AJAX login using Laravel 5.3 Auth.

Here's what I got so far:

```
var login = function()
{
var data = {};

data["email"] = $('#email').val();
data["password"] = $('#password').val();

if($('#remember').is(':checked'))
    data["remember"] = "on";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/login',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    // data: data,
    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },

    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        // window.location.href = "/dashboard";
    }
});
```

};

I'm sending CRSF token as `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header.

The problem is that when I successfully login, I say on the same page,
but in Network tab I can see that `/dashboard` page is loaded by I'm not
redirected.

In the same manner, when I pass wrong credentials, I stay on the same page,
but I can see that `/login` page is loaded in the separate call with an error message that should be actually displayed.

Also, I've tried without `headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },`
and sending data as: `data = data,` but I get the same thing.

Why the browser doesn't redirect to that page since it is loading it in the "background"?

Edit: I'm getting correct page as request response as well, I can see it 
in console (`console.log(data)`;).

Comment: Do you see any error in your AJAX request?

Comment: @Michel No, actually if I refresh login page it will redirect me to dashboard. So it does set session correctly but it doesn't redirect.

Comment: you should manually redirect the user ...  uncomment the last line

Comment: @Sherif, I'd like to be aware that I've got credentials wrong if I miss them.

Comment: The problem might be with the response AJAX request is expecting before redirect. Try the code in my answer.

Comment: if the credentials are wrong wrong you should return response with code 401, which would trigger error function in ajax not success

Comment: I'll write a quick snippet

Comment: @Sherif  I'm trying to utilise Laravel Auth features without overriding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an interesting [solution](http://code4fun.io/post/laravel-ajax-register-and-login?utm_source=learninglaravel.net).

```
/**
 * Get the failed login response instance.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => Lang::get('auth.failed')
        ], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            $this->username() => Lang::get('auth.failed'),
        ]);
}
```

And this:

```
var loginForm = $("#loginForm");
loginForm.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = loginForm.serialize();
    $('#form-errors-email').html("");
    $('#form-errors-password').html("");
    $('#form-login-errors').html("");
    $("#email-div").removeClass("has-error");
    $("#password-div").removeClass("has-error");
    $("#login-errors").removeClass("has-error");
    $.ajax({
        url: '/login',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#loginModal').modal('hide');
            location.reload(true);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data.responseText);
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data.responseText);
            if (obj.email) {
                $("#email-div").addClass("has-error");
                $('#form-errors-email').html(obj.email);
            }
            if (obj.password) {
                $("#password-div").addClass("has-error");
                $('#form-errors-password').html(obj.password);
            }
            if (obj.error) {
                $("#login-errors").addClass("has-error");
                $('#form-login-errors').html(obj.error);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Login FORM
$(document).on('submit', 'form#FormID', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
            var forms = document.querySelector('form#FormID');
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var formDatas = new FormData(forms);
            request.open('post','/login');
            request.send(formDatas);

            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState === 4) {
                    if (request.status === 200) {

                        if (request.responseText == 'success') {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                window.location.href = "/dashboard";
                            }, 5000);
                        }else{

                        };


                    }
                }
            }
});



//Controller
public function authUser(Request $request){
        $data = $request->except('_token');

        $validate = \Validator::make($data, [
            'email' => 'email'
            ]);

        if ($validate->fails())
            return 'Invalid email format for username.';

        if (\Auth::attempt($data)) {
            return 'success';
        }else{
            return 'Invalid username or password';
        }
    }


//Route
Route::post('/login', 'YourController@authUser');
```

The problem might be with the response AJAX request is expecting before redirect.
Try the above code.

Comment: I'm trying to get this working without overriding Laravel Auth features. I'll test this as well and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

in the controller method

```
function login(Request $request){
    if(\Auth::attempt($request)){
        return response()->json('success');
    }else{
        return response()->json('wrong username or pass', 401);
    }
}
```

in ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/login',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    // data: data,
    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },

    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        window.location.href = "/dashboard";
    },
    error : function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I've found solution that is more like "5.3" oriented :)